# java "bean:write " + javascript = "unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, struts-1, struts1

```
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-bean" prefix="bean"%>

form.parentProcessNumberPresentation.value= "<"+ "<bean:write name="associatedProcessField" property="fieldInstruction"/>" + ">";
```

when I print the text with the `"bean: write"` it comes with `"\ n"`, then breaks the string that will be assigned to the components in the form.

how could this filter `"\ n"` to skip it?
I've tried:

```
form.parentProcessNumberPresentation.value= "<"+ "<bean:write name="associatedProcessField" property="fieldInstruction" filter="false"/>" + ">";
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on the version of struts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `"<bean:write name="associatedProcessField" property="fieldInstruction" filter="false"/>"` returned one, but it was with `"\n"` so the string that would be attributed to the JavaScript variable does not was valid.